# How do I do a server-side login to Facebook to read a JSON feed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a purely server-side application that I'm writing that needs to pull a feed from a Facebook page. The page is "age-restricted (alcohol related)" so, doesn't allow the graph API access without an access token.

It works perfectly and returns a perfectly readable JSON feed if the access token is used:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<page_id>/feed?access_token=<access_token>
```

The problem is that access tokens expire. Fortunately I have a "non-related" App_Id and can easily get a new access token by visiting in a browser:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<my_app_id>&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080&scope=manage_pages&response_type=token
```

The first time I visit this URL (in a browser) it asks me to allow "App" to post to "My pages", and of course I say yes. It never asks me again. Now I just get redirected to a new URL, with an awesome access token in it.

```
http://localhost:8080/#access_token=<awesome-access-token>&expires_in=4482
```

I would typically just be able to read this value out of the querystring parameters, but I realised that it's a page framment (#) URL that cannot be read by the server-side code.

I also tried intercepting the first URL redirect, and reading out the 302 LOCATION header, but alas, it seems like a redirect chain.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Follow the steps found in these docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/

Comment: Is the page you are trying to read one you are an admin of? You can get a (nearly) permanent [page access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-page/) to use for these queries.